# Connection error with Elastic Search Python Client

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

I was trying to learn and use the elasticsearch Python client on Windows and got stuck with a connection error.

I ran the `bin\elasticsearch.bat` file that comes with the .zip from the official page: https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch

I opened a Jupyter notebook and tried to run:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch(hosts=["http://localhost:9200"])
es.indices.create(index="users")
```

It returned the following error:

```
ConnectionError: Connection error caused by: ConnectionError(Connection error caused by: ProtocolError(('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))))
```

Is it a problem of not having a correct JSON format when communicating?
How to solve it?

Comment: Did elasticsearch logs have `received plaintext http traffic on an https channel` message?

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure authentication for the client? (maybe not added to the example?)
Check out [the docs about connecting here.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/python-api/current/connecting.html#connect-self-managed-new). You can either use a certificate, or a password, or ideally an API-Key.

Connecting via http only works if you specifically disabled security; so unless you did, that's probably your issue.

Good luck!
Iulia